# Full Disk Encryption on Mac PC with EFI dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, encryption

Recently I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS on my Mac Mini late 2011 using the instructions in [the article "Ubuntu + Mac: Pure EFI Boot"](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/#disqus_thread). Now, I want to do dual boot in my Macbook Pro where I already installed Mac OS Yosemite to Mac OS Extended and encrypted partition.

I read [the article "Full Disk Encryption with Ubuntu"](http://thesimplecomputer.info/full-disk-encryption-with-ubuntu), which is not useful in my case because I am not using LVM. According this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166050/how-to-setup-whole-disk-encryption-with-dual-boot-on-a-macbook-pro-generation-9) two years ago it was not possible to encrypt boot section. A searched for recent updates but there is no clear instructions for Mac installation. So what currently I have is 130Gb free space (no partition) to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop with full disk encryption. What I want to know is:

1. It possible at all on a Macintosh computer?
2. If it is possible, has anyone succeeded in doing it on a Mac? What kind of steps I should follow? (According to article which I follow to install Ubuntu Server I can do home directory encryption without changing steps. However for full disk encryption I also should encrypt /boot section which is modified at the "FIXING THE EFI PARTITION" part from vfat to HFS+. So, may be I should do something different? Can somebody guide me?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/367582/40581) and its reference? Is there any problem you encounter besides needing to bless the UEFI loader? (You may find [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/559008/40581) useful regarding bless.)

Comment: @LiveWireBT currently I want to make pure dual boot efi system without encryption. Because I failed to load it using grub :(

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what your current problem is, unencrypted "dual-boot" EFI on a Mac should work as I wrote in the 2nd link in my previous comment and the first link looked good to me to setup FDE, though using just a LUKS encrypted home partition may be easier to implement. Sorry that I cannot help you further. If I made mistakes or some things are inaccurate please point me to it.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Actually now I am getting understand:

Comment: @LiveWireBT I succeed installing Dual Boot OS (Mac and Ubuntu) in encrypted partitions without refit or refind. What do you thing should I answer my own question and make some kind of tutorial?

Comment: That would be a good idea from my point of view, yes.